# How to determine Jenkins build directory from Ant?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am trying to migrate an Ant script I wrote to build and deploy projects from within the Jenkins framework (instead of triggered from an SVN post-commit hook, which was the expedient way we initially approached things). Everything is great, except I need to stage files for the deploy step and I want to stuff them into the 'build' directory Jenkins creates for the job (and since my build.xml lives in a non-project-specific location, ${basedir} and ${user.dir} do not point to the desired location).

within the Jenkins configuration, I've setup the following:

[Jenkins]
Build Record Root Directory: E:/builds/${ITEM_FULLNAME}

[Job-Specific]
Build File: C:\vc-tools\shadow\build.xml

when running a build, the script is appropriately launched and a job-specific build directory is created, e.g.

E:\builds\Test\2012-08-07_12-51-21

I want to get at this directory from within the build script, but cannot figure out how. some of the things I've tried:

```
 [echo] ${basedir}: C:\vc-tools\shadow
 [echo] ${user.dir}: C:\vc-tools
 [echo] ${env.workspace}: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test
 [echo] ${env.build_id}: 2012-08-07_12-51-21
 [echo] ${jenkins_home}: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins
 [echo] ${BuildDir}: E:/builds/${ITEM_FULLNAME}
```

note: for that last one, I tried passing in:

```
 BuildDir=E:/builds/${ITEM_FULLNAME}
```

as a property configured from the job within Jenkins (clearly ${} expansion doesn't take place in this context).

according to the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables), there are no specific environment variables that are set to the full build directory path -- I can fudge it by hardcoding the E:\builds root and tacking on ${env.build_id}, but was hoping there would be an easier way to access the complete path from something Jenkins exposes (either an Ant property and an environment variable) in order to make the script more flexible.

I am using Jenkins version 1.476.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something very odd, which I don't fully understand. Why is the build.xml file not located in the root directory of the project you're building? Normally you just configure the Jenkins pull the project files out of the SCM system and then run the build... All this happens within the "workspace" which Jenkins manages for that build job.

Comment: Why do you need the directory? You could use relative paths safely

Comment: @MarkO'Connor :- I have a generic build script that can be leveraged for several projects (there is a project-specific property file that the script pulls down to qualify what its doing, but I don't see the value, at the moment, in copying the same build.xml file across multiple, similar, projects).

Comment: @EugenMartynov :- as stated in the question, my script is running out of one location (C:\vc-tools\shadow), the workspace is in another (%JENKINS_HOME%\workspace\<job>) and the build result is in yet another (E:\builds\<job>\%BUILD_ID%). I admit it is a little odd, since you would typically house your build.xml within the project root (or some relative directory), whereas I have mine in a completely unrelated location. I know of no way to relatively address E:\builds from C:\vc-tools\shadow (aside from hardcoding of course).

Comment: @rguilbault I missed point that your build script is inside another directory. Please ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's always a good idea for your project to have a copy of it's build logic included alongside the source code. It makes your build more portable across machines.

Having said that it's also quite common to setup build files containing common shared build logic. ANT defines the following tasks to support such activity:

- [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html)
- [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html)

So a possible solution is to store a simple build.xml file, in the root of your project directory:

```
<project name="my project" default="build">

  <include file="C:\vc-tools\shadow\common-build-1.0.xml" as="common"/>

  <target name="build" depends="common.build"/>

</project>
```

**Notes:**

- It's a good idea to use a revision number in the common build file name. This assists in preserving backward compatibility with other builds using the older logic.

## Update

When Jenkins runs a job is sets a number of [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project).

The following ANT logic will print the location of the Jenkins workspace directory:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<target name="run">
    <echo message="Jenkins workspace: ${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
    <echo message="Job directory: ${env.WORKSPACE}../../jobs/${env.JOB_NAME}"/>
    <echo message="Build data: ${env.WORKSPACE}../../jobs/${env.JOB_NAME}/build/${env.BUILD_ID}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: this looks like it would be very helpful. actually, it is creating some additional advantages beyond the scope of my original question -- thanks for the tip! I'll accept this as the answer once I have a chance to test that it does what I anticipate it will (the only question I have is whether ${basedir} or ${user.dir} will equal ${env.WORKSPACE} or the true 'build' folder that Jenkins sets up)...

Comment: ok, so I still cannot get a reference to the build directory, but it's occurring to me now that I don't need to refer to it (it contains information about the build that Jenkins cares about, it need not be the target for my built project). that said, it would be convenient to use as a staging area (the full scope of what I need to do, for legacy reasons, is checkout/update the workspace from SVN, look for recently changed files and invoke a translator against them to generate object files -- the resulting source and object files then need to be shipped to an SMB-accessible location).

Comment: ...the workspace location is where the checkout/update is going, so I don't want to sully it with staging the files (which, btw, I forgot to mention I need to place in a different tree structure from how they reside in source control). I can create an independent hierarchy (and I might) like E:\staging\${env.BUILD_TAG}, though Jenkins won't automatically clean it up for me, like it would the build directory it manages (I was hoping to create a .staging subdirectory in it, which brings me back to my original question/post).

Comment: @rguilbault not really certain what you're now asking... Staging release artifacts is a whole new question. For example I use the Nexus staging suite to manage the life-cycle of build artifacts. http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging.html

Comment: what is the goal for a build? my expectation was that I would produce some object code files (post translation of source)...in a traditional layout, you might have src and bin folders, where the compiled src files end up in the bin directory, which can all take place in the workspace folder Jenkins checks the project out to -- in my case, though, I need to change the layout of the checked out project to fit the layout our legacy tools expect to see everything -- so compiling to a 'bin' directory is not good enough and I fear the workspace is too communal to place my object code files...

Comment: I had initially thought that the build directory's purpose was to house the generated files. I guess these are build artifacts? while managing all of this stuff through an infrastructure is likely the way to go, my immediate needs are simply to dump the object code files to a directory that has an SMB share, we have other utilities that take the files from there and push to our runtime environments (sorry if I was misleading by using the term deploy -- for me, deploy simply meant pushing the files to the SMB share location). does that clarify?

Comment: @rguilbault You need to consider packaging your code as a JAR or WAR file (dependent on your target platform). This is the standard way to distribute code to users, not directories full of class files. Once your build supports this mechanism you can use a binary file repository like Nexus to keep these release archives versioned. Users can then select whicher version of the app they need to run.

Comment: :- we don't use Java at my company ;-) we're using proprietary, interpreted languages. and my current task is to improve the build process which aims to mimic the 'shadow folder' functionality that VSS provided (we recently migrated to Subversion). it's all baby steps...I originally wrote a post-commit hook which kicks off an Ant script, which works, but kinda sucks, because the developer has to wait. in another question, I was referred to Hudson/Jenkins and just started to play with that (and have been modifying my Ant script accordingly...

Comment: since Jenkins can/will perform the checkout for me, I can cull out a lot of crappy code/script. ultimately, I need to move the files around into a new hierarchy and then push them to an SMB share (for now). once we are comfortable with Jenkins doing this, we can take the next baby step with categorizing build artifacts and whatnot. while I can work around my original question, it does still remain: is there no way to find out what the Jenkins build folder is, from within an Ant script?

Comment: :- thank you for the update, but the workspace is where the svn checkout goes, not where the build data goes (jenkins generates a handful of drop files in the build directory, which is located in the <build.root>\<job.name>\<build.id> folder, where build.root is defined in the jenkins configuration. to my knowledge, there are no environment variAbles setup to this location, though it would be convenient if there were.

Comment: @rguilbault The build data path can be determined relative to the workspace path. See my revised answer. If this doesn't work I would suggest that you resist the temptation to over customize. You entire solution is weird and wonderful (with emphasis on the wonderful!).

Comment: :- this is a good solution that would allow me to avoid having to hardcode the beginning parts of the path; I'll accept it ;-)

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These days (Jenkins v. 1.484) 'run' target from answer above should look like this:

```
<target name="run">
    <echo message="Jenkins workspace: ${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
    <echo message="Job directory: ${env.WORKSPACE}/../../${env.JOB_NAME}"/>
    <echo message="Build data: ${env.WORKSPACE}/../../${env.JOB_NAME}/builds/${env.BUILD_ID}"/>
</target>
```